# VLAN Trunk (Dell 6248 & SMC 8748M)

Tags: dell, vlan, trunk

I have managed to make my VLAN work on both switches :

- Computer #1 from Dell Switch port #20 (VLAN #2) can ping Computer #2 from SMC Switch port #21 (VLAN #2)

What I need to do is :

- Laptop on Dell Switch port #10 (default VLAN #1) can already ping Dell Switch's IP 192.168.0.160 (web interface).  But it cannot ping SMC's IP 192.168.0.161 (web interface).

What I have so far :

Dell trunk config :

```
interface ethernet 1/g1
channel-group 1 mode on
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1-3
exit


!
interface ethernet 1/g2
channel-group 1 mode on
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1-3
exit

interface port-channel 1
gvrp enable
hashing-mode 1
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2-3
exit
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not have

switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1-3

?

Oh and best not use the default vlan if you can avoid it, saves things accidentally ending up connected to networks they shouldn't be.

Comment: I have corrected the line to `switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1-3 ` but it is still not working.   I don't mind not using VLAN 1 (default), I just want to be able to ping both switches...  any other thoughts ?

Comment: whats the config look like on the SMC?